# How is primary key is different from unique key when both are actually serving the same purpose as per my understanding?

Tags: sql, primary-key, unique-key

Primary key is actually the one which cannot be repeated for more than one entries so as the same for unique key as far as I know.

Let's say, we take employee IDs as primary keys for 100 number of employees, this means that employee ID for two employees cannot and can never be same.

But then, what is the unique key? As employee ID is a unique identifier for each employee. What I just know is that the primary key cannot cater `Null` values whereas unique key can cater just one `Null` value.

But is that actually the difference between the two? Can someone, make it more easily understandable preferably with a code example.

Also, after differentiating between two, how can we define both in a single dataset? Are there any set rules which we have to follow.

Comment: If you tell us what you are trying to achieve, you might have a chance to get a better answer than to a general question like this.

Comment: All primary keys (which are never foreign keys in the records they describe) are unique keys.  Not all unique keys (which may be foreign keys) are primary keys.

Comment: The constraints on a table follow from what it records about the current situation & what situations can arise. When a column set must be UNIQUE, we tell the DBMS so it prevents invalid states & can optimize. One UNIQUE NOT NULL column set can be declared as PK. Being NOT NULL, there can't be duplicates of that subrow in the table, otherwise there can, except in SQL Server--it's non-standard. Read the particular DBMS manual about what else comes with a PK declaration. Otherwise, there nothing special about a PK. This is faq. PS Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question per post.

Answer (score 1):

A primary key has three properties:

- The key is unique across all rows of a table.
- The key (or no components of a composite key) are `NULL`.
- There is only one per table.

In general, primary keys are used for foreign key relationships.  They are typically integers, because that is somewhat more efficient for indexing.

Other columns or combinations of columns can be unique and non-`NULL`.  Those are *candidate primary keys*.  However, a table has only one *primary* key.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer will clear your doubt,

- Primary key is used as for foreign key to referencing to different tables.
- *But when we implement large scale Database and our requirement of Referencing more then two Keys from same table to different table(s).*

At that time **unique key** come in scenario and will help you to do the above task easily, as per your(programmer) requirements.

Answer (score 0):

1. Primary key can't have NULL values. Unique key can allows one NULL value.
2. A database table can't have more that one primary key but multiple unique keys are allowed in one table.
3. In sql server a clustered index automatically gets created with the primary key. On the other hand one unique key generates one non-clustered index.

Comment: "one null value" is only in SQL Server & it's contrary to the SQL standard, which allows more that one. (It is possible to declare an index with standard behaviour.)